# Mule Expression Language AND OPERATOR

Tags: java, api, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to use the Mule Expression Language to send two input parameters to an API (ex: CodePostal and LibelleVoie).
I do that :

## [payload[1].getAdresseNonNormalisee().getObjetAttributs().getCodePostal()] && #[payload[1].getAdresseNonNormalisee().getObjetAttributs().getLibelleVoie()]]

But it does not work, it returns me a String

have you an idea please ?

Comment: roger already gave a good answer. by putting object attributes in a flowVar you could improve the readability of the expression: `#[attributes.getCodePostal() && attributes.getLibelleVoie()]`

Comment: Thnx, it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write everything in *one* MEL expression:

```
#[payload[1].getAdresseNonNormalisee().getObjetAttributs().getCodePostal() && 
 payload[1].getAdresseNonNormalisee().getObjetAttributs().getLibelleVoie()]]
```

You used two expressions with some String in between: `" && "`

Comment: Good answer. However for the sack of precision, you need to add `#` at the beginning of your MEL expression. It is used to ask Mule to evaluate the given expression, and not use it as a string.